# Rock Paper Scissor Game...showing only computer as winner for every condition. what mistake i am making

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build rock paper scissor game. In this for every condition it is  showing computer as winner and only the computer score is increasing. In playRound function the conditions are correct i am not able to rectify the problem here. Plz help in finding my mistake.

```
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
var computer;

function computerChoice() {
    const computerId = document.getElementById('computerid');
    computer = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
    computerId.innerHTML = computer;
    console.log(computer);
    return computer;
}

function playRound(computerSel, playerSel) {
    return (computerSel === playerSel) ? "It's a Tie" :
        (computerSel === "rock" && playerSel === "scissors") ||
        (computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "rock") ||
        (computerSel === "scissors" && playerSel === "paper") ? "Computer" : "Player";
    }

var playerSelection;
var computerSelection;
function playGame() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    buttons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
             playerSelection = e.target.textContent;
             console.log(playerSelection);
            const playerId = document.getElementById('playerid');
            playerId.innerHTML = playerSelection;
             computerSelection = computerChoice();
            const result = playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection);
            console.log(result);
            updateScore(result);
            
        });
    });
}

function updateScore(result) {
    const playerscore = document.getElementById('playerscore');
    const computerscore = document.getElementById('computerscore');
   
    if (result === "Player") {
        playerScore++;
    } else if (result === "Computer") {
        computerScore++;
    }
    playerscore.innerText = playerScore;
    computerscore.innerText = computerScore;
    if (playerScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
        endGame();
    }
}

function endGame() {
    const winner = (playerScore > computerScore) ? "Player" : "Computer";
    console.log(`The winner is ${winner}`);
}

playGame();
```

Comment: The only issue I see is that your logic states paper beats rock, rock beats paper, rock beats scissors - other than that small issue your logic works fine ... i.e. `(computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "rock")` should be `(computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "scissors")`

Comment: Note: after fixing that small logic issue, and creating the appropriate HTML, your code works fine

Comment: I have made the changes but still facing same issue.....const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];      function playRound(computerSel, playerSel) {
    if (playerSel === computerSel) {
        return "It's a Tie";
    } else if (
        (computerSel === "rock" && playerSel === "paper") ||
        (computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "scissors") ||
        (computerSel === "scissor" && playerSel === "rock")
    ) {
        return "Player";
    } else {
        return "Computer";
    }
}

Comment: You have a mix of "scissor" and "scissors". Make it consistent. Note that it really should be [with the final "s"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/233923) to be valid English.

Comment: Could you please add the rest of the document to the question?

Comment: @Phil This is the git hub repository for Rock,Paper,Scissor game i am working on. https://github.com/Riyaonweb/Rock-Paper-Scissors ...you will find all files here..

Answer (score 0):

I think there issue with condition. you have to update the condition in the playRound function.

```html
function playRound(computerSel, playerSel) {
    if (playerSel === computerSel) {
        return "It's a Tie";
    } else if (
        (computerSel === "rock" && playerSel === "scissor") ||
        (computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "rock") ||
        (computerSel === "scissor" && playerSel === "paper")
    ) {
        return "Computer";
    } else {
        return "Player"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: all you've done is inversed the check from checking how the player wins to checking how the computer wins - how is that "updating the condition in the playRound function"?

Comment: the logic for checking rounds in the op is wrong, the new logic in this post is correct. specifically they've adjusted the 3rd condition in the playRound function (which was wrong) and swapped which player name is returned to actually match with the logic of the surrounding code

Comment: no, the only logic error is the second condition `(computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "rock")` should've been `(computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "scissor")` - inverting the logic isn't showing what they did wrong

Answer (score 0):

you are checking wrong condition for player win in your else if

second statement login is wrong just replace "rock" with "scissor" for player win condition.

```
else if (
    (computerSel === "rock" && playerSel === "paper") ||
    (computerSel === "paper" && playerSel === "scissor") ||
    (computerSel === "scissor" && playerSel === "rock")
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your question is correct for rock, paper scissors:

- Rock breaks scissors
- Paper wraps rock
- Scissors cuts paper

The one line grammer of the if statement as seen below:

```js
function playRound(c,p){
    return (p == c) ? "Its a Tie" :
    (c == "rock" && p == "scissors") ||
    (c == "paper" && p == "rock") ||
    (c == "scissors" && p == "paper") ? "computer won" : "player won";
}
```

Needs an extra pair of parenthesis:

```js
function playRound(c,p){
    return (p == c) ? "Its a Tie" :
    ((c == "rock" && p == "scissors") ||
    (c == "paper" && p == "rock") ||
    (c == "scissors" && p == "paper")) ? "computer won" : "player won";
}
```

This is, logically, the same reason why

```js
3 x 6 + 2 = 20
is not 
3 x (6 + 2) = 24
```

This particular issue seems to be resolved in your repository.